# Creating Excel file no longer working in AppleScript

Tags: excel, applescript

I have an AppleScript that worked just fine when executing this simple command:

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set temp to make new document
```

and from there I would add all kinds of things to the new spreadsheet, but now when that command executes, I get an error: "Microsoft Excel got an error: Parameter error."

I'm using Big Sur on a MacBook Pro M1, but I can't imaging that is relevant, since the script was originally created and ran fine on the same setup.

The script worked as is just last week. What parameter should I add (and how) to overcome the error, and why is the command so fragile that it worked before and not now, with no changes to the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you update anything else?

Comment: Since you don't have any parameters at all, try adding one. Conceivably, the dictionary for Excel will show what is required for the command. On Sierra, it specifies that `at` is required (but they're fibbing). So take a look at the dictionary for the make command and see what it indicates there. Maybe Apple decided to begin enforcing this. Maybe try adding `at front window` after 'new document'.